# Querying an object array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

As my level of oop in Javascript is not as I wish it was, this is my workaround to access an array of objects.

One array has the object (`HelmT`) and one for the id's so i could easily access first by `id`,and that way, also access the real array and get the object by it's "ID" property fetched from IDs array.

What is the correct way to manage an array of object?

... and off course have an `Add` - `Remove` 
and most important `getElementBy_SomeProperty()`

```
var Objcoll ={
    _CoreLstsIDs{_arr[],isready:false},
    _CoreLsts{_arr[],isready:false},
    HElmTColl_FindById: function (parId) {
        var collindexofCurFileReadyDivWrpFlds =  this.getIdxOfCurHElmTinColl_ID(parId);
        return this._CorLsts._arr[collindexofCurFileReadyDivWrpFlds];
    },
    getIdxOfCurHElmTinColl_ID: function (parId) {
        return $.inArray(parId, this._CorLstsIDs._arr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Where's the arrays? How do we know what to look for to hook into?

Comment: @zer00ne  i have tried to post as less code as possible, but i have posted all the basic, the array is, for id's:  `_CoreLstsIDs._arr` and for object itself `_CoreLsts._arr` i do not get what's missing , maybe i should post more of my full code...

Comment: id is vague. id's of an object? ids of arbitrary strings? If there was any content to process, what are you expecting? How are we to test anything if not told what you want as a result? Manage an array of objects? Manage is vague without a purpose or content to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to manage an array is by treating it as an array. JavaScript Arrays have [lots of functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which you can leverage directly to achieve your goals.

For example,

```
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  content: 'foo'
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: 'bar'
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: 'baz'
}];

var findById = function(id) {
  return arr.find(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
}

var findByProperty = function(prop, value) {
  return arr.find(function(element) {
    return element[prop] === value;
  });
}

findById(1) // {"id":1,"content":"foo"}
findById(2) // {"id":2,"content":"bar"}
findByProperty('content', 'baz') // {"id":3,"content":"baz"}
```

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  content: 'foo'
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: 'bar'
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: 'baz'
}];

var findById = function(id) {
  return arr.find(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
}

var findByProperty = function(prop, value) {
  return arr.find(function(element) {
    return element[prop] === value;
  });
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(findById(1)) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(findById(2)) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(findByProperty('content', 'baz')) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: cheers it's simple and easy and exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot @Hamms